# Java unisex bathroom

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I have to solve this problem using Java semaphores, but I have no idea how, and I cannot find any related Java materials. This is how it goes:

There are to kinds of threads: men and women. Both wants to use same resources which quantity is BATHROOM_SIZE. 5 rules:

1. Every thread, after signaling need of using resource, should wait until he will be able to use it.
2. Prevent situation, when more than BATHOOM_SIZE threads is using resource concurrently.
3. Prevent woman and man use bathoom in the same time.
4. Threads should use resources concurrently. If there are many threads of one type, up to BATHROOM_SIZE threads should use resource.
5. Prevent starvation.

### Results

#### Works for:

1woman, 1man, 5women, 5men

#### Fails for:

5women1men, 5men1women, 2men2women, 5men5women.

I've been trying to make it work since Monday and now I've run out of ideas.

### Code

So my task is to write *Bathroom.java* class which implements *BathroomInterface*:

```
public interface BathroomInterface {

    public static final int BATHROOM_SIZE = 3; //3 is just example
    void manEnter();
    void manExit();
    void womanEnter();
    void womanExit();
}
```

In system there are a number of man and woman threads which work like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  bathroom.manEnter();
  //uses bathroom random amount of time
  bathroom.manExit();
}

for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  bathroom.womanEnter();
  //uses bathroom random amount of time
  bathroom.womanExit();
}
```

I also have scheme of *Bathroom.java* class, I have to extend:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Bathroom implements BathroomInterface {

    
    private Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1, true);

    public void womanEnter() {
        mutex.acquireUninterruptibly();
    }

    public void womanExit() {
        mutex.release();
    }

    public void manEnter() {
        mutex.acquireUninterruptibly();        
    }

    public void manExit() {
        mutex.release();
    }
}
```

This is what I made so far:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Bathroom implements BathroomInterface {
    int manW=0, manU=0, womanW=0, womanU=0; //*U-using, *W-waiting
    private Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1, false);

    public void womanEnter() {
        womanW++;
        StateChange();
    }

    public void womanExit() {
        womanU--;
        mutex.release();
        StateChange();
    }

    public void manEnter(){
        manW++;
        StateChange();
    }

    public void manExit() {
        manU--;
        mutex.release();
        StateChange();
    }
    
    void StateChange() {
        if(womanU==0 && manU==0) {
            if(manW>womanW) {
                while(manW>0 && manU<BATHROOM_SIZE) {
                    manW--;
                    manU++;
                    mutex.acquireUninterruptibly();
                }
            }
            else {
                while(womanW>0 && womanU<BATHROOM_SIZE) {
                    womanW--;
                    womanU++;
                    mutex.acquireUninterruptibly();
                }
            }
        }
        if(womanU==0 && manU<BATHROOM_SIZE) {
            while(manW>0 && manU<BATHROOM_SIZE) {
                manW--;
                manU++;
                mutex.acquireUninterruptibly();
            }
        }
        if(manU==0 && womanU<BATHROOM_SIZE) {
            while(womanW>0 && womanU<BATHROOM_SIZE) {
                womanW--;
                womanU++;
                mutex.acquireUninterruptibly();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "fail"? Does it get deadlocked, crash, freeze, throw an exception, ...? Remember, the more details you give, the better help you get.

Comment: ok i have some questions. Why are you using a size=1 semaphore if your bathroom has more capacity? semaphores are created in order to automatically manage multiple-same-type-resources.

Comment: That has got to be the best multithreading homework assignments I have ever seen.

Comment: Every bathroom should prevent starvation

Comment: they are all the same, specially the ones like this which are supposed to use monitors: unisex bathroom, one way at the time bridge, one way at the time apron...

Comment: @Th0rndike No idea, in class scheme is 1 so i use 1. But if you know how to do this other way, there is no problem to use bigger semaphores.

Comment: I think the size=1 semaphore is actually a hint to the solution. The mutex does not guard the size of the bathroom, it guards the entry door and allows the bathroom to not care about where people wait.

Comment: @wallenborn yeah, i'm doing it that way. Freaking multithreading it's a mess.

Comment: So, i wrote up the solution. Now i don't know what to do. I feel that if i post the solution i would be ruining OP homework, but i also feel that posting only a part of the solution would not explain a thing to the student. What to do?

Comment: I'm in a similar spot. Maybe post a simplified solution, without the prevent starvation stuff, and maybe without the unisex aspect? OP has to implement a complicated concurrency object, and showing him how to implement a simple one might put him on the right path without solving it for him.

Answer (score 7):

Actually this exercise is done using a monitor, and not a semaphore. What you're doing is mostly fine, you're missing the conditions. So, in your bathroom class, declare:

a lock:

```
private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

2 conditions or queues, attached to your lock:

```
private Condition womenWaitingQueue = lock.newCondition();
private Condition menWaitingQueue = lock.newCondition();
```

2 counters to know how many are waiting,  and 2 to know how many are using:

```
private int womenWaitingN = 0;
private int menWaitingN = 0;
private int womenUsingN = 0;
private int menUsingN = 0;
```

and of course, the number of resources:

```
private final int BATHROOM_CAPACITY = 5;
private int free_resources = BATHROOM_CAPACITY;
```

*all 4 functions were here, but removed because of the homework tag*

The important thing here is to prevent starvation, by not allowing any men to enter the bathroom if there are women waiting and viceversa.

so, conditions are that if a man wants to enter to the bathroom, it has to check if the bathroom has at least 1 free spot (using free resources) and if there are women in the bathroom (using womenUsingN). If any of these 2 conditions are not met, the man must wait(using the menWaitingQueue):

```
menWaitingQueue.await();
```

when a man leaves the bathroom, it has to check if there are any women waiting (womenWaitingN), if there are, they get notified:

```
womanWaitingQueue.signal();
```

because of the menUsingN counter, women signaled by this wont be able to enter until there are no men in the bathroom. If there are no women waiting, then a man can be signaled to enter the bathroom. This prevents starvation because priority is given to the opposite sex (if waiting).

The last thing, is that every function must lock/unlock the **lock** at beginning/end of each enter/exit function.

```
lock.lock();
lock.unlock();
```

I think with this new information you'll be able to make the functions on your own. Good luck!

Comment: +1 Starvation prevention is actually the most interesting aspect of the problem, because there is no single correct answer. Usually you wind up with something that works like a traffic light and switches priority periodically. I like your switch-on-exit idea a lot: bathroom is empty and gets filled with waiting women. The first to exit triggers the switch, so after the bathroom empties, it gets filled with waiting men, first to exit triggers it again. That's a nice combination of fairness and performance, and avoids the "wait at a red light on an empty road" anomaly traffic lights often have.

Answer (score 2):

I think you struggle with the whole mutex.acquire and mutex.release semantics, especially with what the mutex is actually supposed to guard. Let me try to simplify the problem a little to give you a hint as to how to approach this.

You are asked to implement a concurrency object that's more complicated than a simple semaphore, with two client classes and starvation prevention. I'm not going to do that for you, but i'm going to show you how a simple semaphore looked like in the pre-Java6 days:

```
public class Resource {

    private int numClients = 0;
    private final int maxClients;

    public Resource(int maxClients) {
        this.maxClients = maxClients;
    }

    public synchronized void acquire() {
        while (!clientCanAcquire()) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        ++numClients;
        printState();
    }

    public synchronized void release() {
        --numClients;
        printState();
        notify();
    }

    private boolean clientCanAcquire() {
        return numClients < maxClients;
    }

    private void printState() {
        System.out.println("Resource is currently acquired by " + numClients
                + " clients");
    }
}
```

A Client can access this as follows:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Client implements Runnable {

    private Resource resource;
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    public Client(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(rnd.nextInt(1000));
            resource.acquire();
            Thread.sleep(rnd.nextInt(1000));
            resource.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

and the simplest application that can drive the whole thing would look like this:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        Resource r = new Resource(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Thread client = new Thread(new Client(r));
            client.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Resource stores the information it needs to determine when a client can access in internal variables. In a multithreaded application, access to these variables must be synchronized. Shown here is the simplest way to do this, but you could also say

```
private Object mutex = new Object();
```

and then

```
synchronized (mutex) { }
```

or any other type of mutex.

Your problem is more complicated than a simple ordinary semaphore, but the underlying logic should be pretty similar.

Comment: nice example. I think with this and my answer user will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

@Th0rndike ok, i followed your hints and wrote sth like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class Bathroom implements BathroomInterface {
    private Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1, false);

    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition womenWaitingQueue = lock.newCondition();
    private Condition menWaitingQueue = lock.newCondition();

    private int womenWaitingN = 0;
    private int menWaitingN = 0;
    private int womenUsingN = 0;
    private int menUsingN = 0;

    private int free_res = BATHROOM_SIZE;

    public void womanEnter() {
        lock.lock();
        if(free_res>0 && menUsingN==0) {
            womenUsingN++;
            free_res--;
            mutex.acquireUninterruptibly();
        }
        else
            try {
                womenWaitingQueue.await();
            }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("E!");
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public void womanExit() {
        lock.lock();
        womenUsingN--;
        free_res++;
        mutex.release();
        if(menWaitingN>0) {
            try {
                menWaitingQueue.signal();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("E!");
            }
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public void manEnter() {
        lock.lock();
        menUsingN++;
        free_res--;
        if(free_res>0 && womenUsingN==0) {
            mutex.acquireUninterruptibly();
        }
        else
            try {
                menWaitingQueue.await();
            }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("E!");
        }
        lock.unlock();    
    }

    public void manExit() {
        lock.lock();
        menUsingN--;
        free_res++;
        mutex.release();
        if(womenWaitingN>0) {
            try {
                womenWaitingQueue.signal();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("E!");
            }
        }
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

But when I submit it to the automated program checker, in 1man and 1woman tests everything is ok, but in the rest, it returns "realtime exceeded" error. If I remove lock.lock()/unlock(), "realtime exceeded" errors will change to "wrong answer".

Comment: You don't need the semaphore anymore. Also, when adding a woman to the queue you're not incrementing the womanWaitingN counter(same for men). Another thing you're missing is the waiting while: If a woman gets signaled, the conditions to enter the bathroom must be checked again before allowing them to enter, specially because we cannot let a woman enter if there are men inside the bathroom, and they could get signaled in this condition, so, there has to be a while loop where if conditions are not met, the woman gets in queue again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution at http://se.inf.ethz.ch/courses/2013a_spring/ccc/

You may refer that for some help.

Comment: You necro'd a year-old question to post a link-only answer?

Comment: I was searching for this solution. I found answer I saw this page on SO. I thought it would be helpful and so posted here.